# server is disconneting database

Tags: php, mysql

database get connected successfully....but...
here is my code

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'databasename';

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Database Not Connected");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Database Not Fount");

?>
```

but the database is regularly disconnecting and connecting after 30-40 minutes....please help me, that what's going on.....

Comment: How does this disconnection express itself? Do you get an error message? Is there any session management involved?

Comment: "but the database is regularly disconnecting and connecting after 30-40 minutes"

- This statement doesn't make a lot of sense. Do you mean your PHP client script routeinely runs for longer than 30 minutes? 

Is this a dedicated DBMS or is it a shared host? Have you checked the DBMS log files?

What's the config for the MySQL client and DBMS? How many cnxns are there when it starts dropping them? Is MySQL running on the same machine as the PHP code or could there be a firewall in between? Are you paying someone someone to provide/support this service?
...and a hundred more questions.
C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to close your connection with [mysql_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php)().

Too many connections will cause problems so that might explain your disconnects.

Comment: At the end of your script, testkhan.

Comment: From the manual ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php ): Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the problem of confusing variables. Your connection and db-selection shouldn't be confused with queries that will run at a later time.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT id, username FROM users";
```

In this example, `$conn` will not be used to reference anything other than my resource. My query, ran at a later time, will be known as `$query`, so as to not confuse myself.

I would also suggest watching the execution times of your queries, and the number of concurrent connections opened. If you need to, be sure to close your connections:

```
mysql_close($conn); // note the importance of a unique variable here
```